# Group by as JPA

Tags: sql, jpa

With plain SQL:

```
select e.* 
from (
  select type, source, max(timestamp) as maxtimestamp 
  from handelse 
  group by type, source
) other join event e 
  on e.type=other.type and 
     e.source=other.source and 
     e.timestamp = other.maxtimestamp 
  join eventpost ep on e.id = ep.event_id;
```

the **event** record with the latest time stamp.  What sucks is that JPA doesn't allow for sub-selects in the from clause.  Any ideas how to re-write the query into something that JPA can swallow?  Underlying database is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

After toying around I moved the aggregation into the where clause:

```
select e 
  from Event e left join fetch e.eventpost 
where e.timestamp=(select max(o.timestamp) 
                   from Event o 
                   where o.type=e.type and 
                   o.source=e.source);
```